# C# Database MasterReset

Tags: c#, database

I'm not sure if this is possible and I can't find any answers anywhere else.

Is it possible to have a blank OleDb database stored in the Folders of a Project in C# and after a buttonClick replace the current database (that's being used) with the blank Database?

I'm not looking for a way to save the data from the original somewhere else, although I can understand how that is useful and good practice.

I'm primarily interested in whether this is possible, and how I would go about learning how to use it in my system.

Thanks for reading, and thanks in advance for any help or suggestions :)

Comment: The question is not clear to me. You want just to work with different database (dynamically switch target), or you really need replace original database by empty one? Which database do you use?

Comment: Sorry if its not clear, I wonder if its possible to replace the 'Original' database with a blank copy

Comment: The world would be much more interesting & perhaps happier place to live in if only all the applications had the `Destroy all the data` button! Just press it & throw your laptop away...

Comment: OleDbDatabase, I'll add all this to the Question.

Comment: @Vojtěch Dohnal I'm sorry I don't understand your meaning

Comment: Just trying to say that it could be quite a hazard to give the user a button that deletes at once the whole database.

Comment: It's not a button on the first form if that's what you think. I'm trying to create a full user oriented program for managing employee holidays. My though was if the user wanted to Reset the data, he'd click setting, click masterreset, click yes on are you sure, then click a checkbox and enter a password.

Comment: your database file would be locked while you use it, so you can't just replace it. But as soon as all connections are closed, you could rename the current database file, copy your blank template file over and re-connect to the now blank database. If you don't need the data from the original database anywhere, you could also just run a script that truncates all tables in your database instead of fiddling with database files.

Comment: I understand it is a hazard to give a user this option, however the program is for my Boss, and he's not a potato so probably wont delete all the data if he didn't want to

Comment: after reading your last comment: why not let the user create files (call them "project" or "schedule" or "plan") instead of always using the one database file? So the user could start fresh by creating a new database with a new filename himself and if he wants to go back to the old file, he always can.

Comment: @Dirk Trilsbeek that sounds like what I expected to here. Would it be difficult to work this into a project?

Comment: That is a brilliant Idea that I hadn't thought of! How practical is it to have a user create and name a file? Wouldn't it create problems when trying to Query the databases? Since they may have different names?

Comment: you'd just need to have some "open project" dialog and maybe a recent files list in your menu to enable users to select a file. Then you would have to connect to that file, yeah. A little bit more difficult than using a single file in a fixed destination, but not by much.

Comment: Well thanks for all the help, I'll give this a go and hopefully have a better formatted program at the end of it. Would you want to post what you have written as an answer so I can check it and have this question marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest instead of using a fixed database file the user has to "reset", allowing the user to create multiple database files that he can choose from. Most office applications have "create file"/"open file"-dialogs, so users are very familiar with them. You may want to implement an "open last file" or "recent files list"-feature for convenience.

First of all, this would allow the user to start fresh without having to throw away his old data. A user would also be much less reluctant to create something new than to "reset" something (as he should be), so that would also help in user experience terms.

Secondly, disconnecting a database or truncating the contents can work, but it is not as simple as it first sounds. If you're still connected to the database, the file will be locked and you can't remove it. The truncate approach can also cause problems, not only does your whole application have to be able to deal with a suddenly empty database, existing foreign key constraints will have to be considered too.